# Global Array of Functions pointers

Tags: c++

How to make a global array of functions in C++?

I want this:

```cpp
//f.cpp
#include "head.h"
void f() {};
```

```cpp
//g.cpp
#include "head.h"
void g() {};
```

```cpp
//head.h
#pragma once
void f();
void g();

typedef void (*f_t)();
f_t Fs[2] = {f,g};
```

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "head.h"

int main() {
    Fs[0]();
}
```

Something like this worked for me in C, but I'm new to C++. I tried a lot of way's of compiling stuff but, each time, g++ gave me "multiple definitions" errors.

How to create global arrays without initialising it through a function?

I tried to implement the same but with the array in a separate "const_array.h" file; that solves the problem but, when I include it to other files, it gives me anyway the same error.

Comment: If more than one source file `#include`s `head.h` (either directly or via other headers) then you'll get multiple definition errors for `Fs`.   That is true in both C and C++.   Since `f.cpp`, `g.cpp`, and `main.cpp` all `#include "head.h"`, you'll have multiple definition errors.   You need to fix your source and header files so only ONE source file ever sees the definition of `Fs`.

Comment: Or as of C++17, you can leave it in the header file but just add `inline` to the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more file:

```
//head.h
#pragma once
void f();
void g();

typedef void (*f_t)();
extern f_t Fs[2];
```

```
//head.cpp
#include "head.h"
f_t Fs[2] = {f,g};
```

Comment: thank, is this the clean and safe way ?

Comment: If course yes. This is the same as `void f();` in a header file and `void f() {}` in a cpp file. The only difference is a function declaration is extern by default.